# boolean value not changed

Tags: c++, qt

I'm trying to use a boolean value to keep the state I'm in. 
In my header file, I declare:

```
bool *modified;
```

In my class constructor I initialize the state at false:

```
bool initState = false;
modified = &initState;
```

I then have a button that change the state to true:

```
bool change = true;
modified = &change;
```

I also have a button to see the state:

```
if(!*modified){
    // doing something 
} else{
   // do something else 
}
```

The issue is if I actually changed the state, ***!*modified*** will still be at true. I'm at a loss to see where the problem lies. Does anyone have any ideas where it is.

Comment: why are you using a boolean pointer when a plain boolean will do? your code snippet is not complete enough to explain your error

Comment: Are `change` and `initState` local variables, by chance?

Comment: It's not a great idea to have the definition of `modified` in a header because you run the risk of multiple definitions if more than one source file includes it. Better to use `extern` to declare in the header file and define once in a source file.

Comment: I am not sure why you are using a pointer for this. But it appears you are setting the address of your pointer to local variables which will go out of scope. Once they go out of scope their values can change randomly. So I think you have UB (Undefined Behavior).

Comment: If you just had a plain boolean then assigning the value of a local boolean would persist the state you've complicated matters by using a pointer

Comment: I understand it now. I'm switching to plain bool now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are changing the value of `modified`, which is a `bool*`, and maybe to point to stack-allocated data which will be destroyed on function return. You want to change the value which is *pointed to* by `modified`.

```
bool initState = false;
*modified = initState;

bool change = true;
*modified = change;
```

This is assuming that the `modified` pointer is actually allocated somewhere.

Comment: thanks I see what i did wrong. from the comments above I'll just use a plain bool for it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
if (!(*modified))
else


bool change = true;
*modified = change;

bool initState = false;
*modified = initState;
```

Answer (score 0):

try this code
    bool *modified;

```
bool initState = false;
modified = initState;   false

bool change = true;  
modified = change; true

if ( *modified != initState)
{
do something
}
else 
{
do something
}
```